# How to use static_assert within an initializer in C?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, static-analysis

Believe it or not, I want to use `static_assert` in a macro that expands to a designated initializer:

```
#define INIT(N) \
        /* static_assert((N) < 42, "too large"), */ \
        [(N)] = (N)

int array[99] = { INIT(1), INIT(2), INIT(42) };
```

I want an error from `INIT(42)`, but uncommenting the `static_assert` is a syntax error. AFAIK `static_assert` is syntactically a declaration. How can I use it in this example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#define INIT(N) \
    [(N)] = (sizeof((struct {_Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large");char c[N];}){{0}}.c))
```

... I'm not sure myself how I ended up with that abomination. But hey, it works (for `N > 0`) !

```
// A struct declaration is a valid place to put a static_assert
        struct {_Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large");          }
// Then we can place that declaration in a compound literal...
       (struct {_Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large");          }){   }
// But we can't just throw it away with `,`: that would yield a non-constant expression.
// So let's add an array of size N to the struct...
       (struct {_Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large");char c[N];}){{0}}
// And pry N out again through sizeof!
sizeof((struct {_Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large");char c[N];}){{0}}.c)
```

`0`-friendly version (just adding then subtracting `1` so the array has a positive size):

```
#define INIT(N) \
    [(N)] = (sizeof((struct { \
        _Static_assert((N) < 42, "too large"); \
        char c[(N) + 1]; \
    }){{0}}.c) - 1)
```

Comment: Great! But no need to create a compound literal, just take `sizeof` the anonymous `struct`.

Comment: @not-a-user no, that wouldn't be portable -- in fact, I reckon common aligmnent rules would make, for example, `sizeof` equal 4 with N = 3. But nothing is actually created anyway, because we're in an unevaluated context :)

Comment: What about `#define ZASSERT(x, m) (0 * sizeof(struct{_Static_assert((x), m); char dummy;}))` and `#define INIT(N) [(N)] = (N) + ZASSERT((N) < 42, "too large")`? Looks portable and reusable to me.

Comment: @not-a-user yes, that looks fine.